# Select distinct rows from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, distinct, nosql

How do you select distinct records in MongoDB? This is a pretty basic db functionality *I believe* but I can't seem to find this anywhere else.

Suppose I have a table as follows

```
--------------------------
| Name    | Age          |
--------------------------
|John     | 12           |
|Ben      | 14           |
|Robert   | 14           |
|Ron      | 12           |
--------------------------
```

I would like to run something like `SELECT DISTINCT age FROM names WHERE 1;`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks [like there is a SQL mapping chart](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart) that I overlooked earlier.

Now is a good time to say that using a distinct selection isn't the best way to go around querying things. Either cache the list in another collection or keep your data set small.

Answer (score 25):

`db.names.distinct('age')`